# How to add null value to global secondary index in DynamoDB?

Tags: kotlin, amazon-dynamodb

I have an attribute called `foo` which is a global secondary index in DynamoDB. `foo` is of type string which can also be null. I am using the following code to map `foo` to dynamodb.

```
    val fooAttributeValue = foo?.let {
                AttributeValue.builder().s(it).build()
            } ?: AttributeValue.builder().nul(true).build()

val putItemRequest = PutItemRequest
            .builder()
            .item(
                mapOf(COLUMN_NAME to fooAttributeValue)
            .tableName(tableName)
            .build()
        dynamoDbClient.putItem(putItemRequest)
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
{"errorMessage":"One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for Index Key foo Expected: S Actual: NULL
```

I know that we cannot insert null in global secondary index in dynamodb. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see we cannot use Null as a key value. As this attribute is also a key for your index it must contain a non null and non empty string.

DynamoDB supports a schemaless schema, and also supports sparse indexes. So if you require those items not to appear in your index, then simply don't include that attribute.

If you do want to see those items in your index and you don't want your index to be sparse, then set the value to a string `"NULL"` and have your application logic handle it.